# Convert spark row to case class and fail if value is null

Tags: apache-spark

I want to convert a Dataframe to Dataset[CC].

```
case class CC(id: String, value: String)
df.as[CC]
```

However if in the id or value is null I would like the operation to throw an exception. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this way:

```
 val ds = df.map(s=>{
    s.toSeq.foreach(x=>{
      if (x == null) throw new Exception("null value: "+s.mkString(","))
    })
    new CC(s.getString(0),s.getString(1))
  })
```

```
    +----+----+
    | _c0| _c1|
    +----+----+
    |   1|   a|
    |   2|null|
    |   3|   b|
    |null|null|
    |   5|null|
    +----+----+
```

and exception:

```
`Caused by: java.lang.Exception: null value: 2,null`
```